# Проверить наличие содержимого в блоке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок, внутри которого находится текст и другие блоки, и прочие элементы. Нужно вывести сообщение "блок пуст" если внутри него ничего нет.

```js
var uscont = $('.user-profile').html();

if (uscont !== "") {
  alert(1);
} else {
  alert('Блок пуст');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="user-profile">erfregrt4grtghrthg gbtrghrthtr htrhtrhtrhtrhrt
  <div class="profile">
    d3f4rfg45g45g gfr4g45g54 g45g45g54g
    <div class="file">
      d3f4rfg45g45g gfr4g45g54 g45g45g54g
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

в моем коде вне зависимости от того, есть ли в блоке элементы или нет, все равно выводится 1.
Заметил что учитывается даже перенос строки. И если из родительского блока удалить все и закрывающий тег поставить на той же строке, то все работает.

**Так как все таки проверить родительский блок на наличие контента внутри, не обращая внимания на пробелы и переносы строк?**

Comment: У вас не правильная верстка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто надо [отримить](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp), чтобы удалить пробелы и символы перевода строки, в услови должно быть `uscont.trim().length != 0`

Answer (score 1):

`$('.user-ptofile').children().length` покажет есть ли кто то внутри